Is sublease income considered passive income and subject to tax reporting?
I am an F-1 student who subleased my apartment last summer while on OPT. I have read that F-1 students are allowed to receive limited passive income, but I am unsure whether income from subleasing is considered passive income, similar to rental income.
A lawyer I consulted mentioned that F-1 students are not allowed to receive any income, and subleasing at a higher rate than my original rent could potentially violate this rule. This has left me with several questions:

Is sublease income considered passive income for F-1 students? Does it require tax reporting?
What factors determine whether income is considered active or passive? Is it based on the nature of the income or the amount?
Does subleasing at a higher rate than my original rent disqualify the income from being considered passive?


I was told that F-1 students cannot receive any income - I don't believe that to be true.

I'm fairly certain that active income refer to wages, so income that isn't from wages (i.e. you selling your time for money) is passive. For the non-wage income, you actually have to profit for it to be income, which is what your lawyer is referring to; (revenue-cost) has to be positive, which in this case meaning the amount you're are charging for the sublease is greater than what your landlord is charging you rent for the lease. I don't know anything specific about F-1 students but generally, all income has to be reported, but you aren't liable for taxes until a specific amount.

When filing taxes, you deduct all costs (e.g. What you pay to the bank if you were leasing instead of sub-leasing) from your revenue, and that's what you report. The only exception is when the costs are from illegal activity; e.g. if your business is selling drugs then you can't deduct the cost of them when reporting income.

@uberhaxed: for US tax residents at least $14.6-35.4k income (depending on status, for 2024) isn't taxed because of the standard deduction; however, foreign students and scholars, including F-1, are for the first several years considered nonresident even though physically present, and nonresident tax has no standard deduction (except for students from India) and limited itemized deductions for 'effectively-connected' income -- which I think sublease would be

Subleasing income isn't similar to rental income; it is rental income.

@dave_thompson_085 Could you explain why sublease income would be considered "effectively connected" income and how it relates to active/passive income? I also noticed there is also not-for-profit rental income. Although I made a profit during the period I subleased, the total income I received is less than the total rent I paid for the year. In this case, can such income be reported as not-for-profit rental income instead?

@phoog Does this mean that sublease income is still considered passive income, even if I sublease at a higher rate than my original rent and make a profit? My main confusion is how to report this income - should it be classified as effectively connected income on Schedule E, or as not-for-profit rental income on Schedule 1?


A lawyer I consulted mentioned that F-1 students are not allowed to receive any income

IANAL, but that doesn't sound right.

Is sublease income considered passive income for F-1 students? Does it require tax reporting?

It's definitely income and should be reported on your tax return. Depending on the circumstances it may be taxable (depending on what you can, if at all, deduct from it as an eligible expense).

What factors determine whether income is considered active or passive? Is it based on the nature of the income or the amount?

Passive or active nature of activity depends on the specifics of the activity. Long term rentals are generally considered passive, while short term rentals with hotel-like services (aka AirBNB) are generally considered active. You'll need to determine, based on your specific facts and circumstances, where you fall on that range. See the IRS Publication 925.

Does subleasing at a higher rate than my original rent disqualify the income from being considered passive?

No, generally passive investments are still investments and are intended for profit.

Thanks for the response! However, it seems that you didn’t address whether sublease income is considered passive income for F-1 students. I referred to the IRS Publication, which states that rental activity is considered passive income, even if there is material participation. That being said, other agencies like SEVP and USCIS may evaluate sublease income differently than IRS does for taxation purposes. If sublease income is indeed considered passive, how would this income be classified?

@nano what does SEVP or USCIS have to do with anything? This is a financial forum, not an immigration forum.
